# However does UDP socket receiver buffer size impact latency?

Tags: sockets, multicast, latency

I am setting the multicast UDP socket receiver buffer size to a big value to avoid packet drop. I tried to use a small buffer size, I did not see any latency diff. I am wondering how does it impact latency? When the app is fast enough to handle incoming packets, does bigger socket buffer size really impact latency and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP latency is going to depend more on the network that you're passing the traffic through than the local configuration. Small buffer size will mean you drop packets more often for high throughput streams but that isn't technically a latency issue. Latency will be affected by your local machine by how fast you can pull packets out of the buffer which will be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't impact latency at all. It just uses extra memory, that's why it's tuneable.